# Weird behavior of istringstream object instantiated with a null-terminated character string in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, istringstream

I have a null-terminated character string stored in `s` of type `char*`. I want to create an `istringstream` object from `s`. Since the constructor of `istringstream` expects a parameter of type `string`, I need to convert `s` from `char*` to `string`. I did this by creating an anonymous `string` object from `s` using its constructor in the following way:

```
istringstream strin(string(s));
```

This seems OK when compiled using gcc (4.7.3). However, after I added the following codes to use `strin`

```
int r;
strin >> r;
```

I got the compile error:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'std::istringstream(std::string*) {aka std::basic_istringstream<char>(std::basic_string<char>*)}' and 'int' to binary 'operator>>'
```

This seems weird to me since I don't understand what the type `std::istringstream(std::string*)` is. Shouldn't `strin` be of type `std::istringstream`?

I can keep the compiler happy by using one of the following modified versions of the code.

Solution 1: pass a named `string` object

```
string str(s);
istringstream strin(str);
```

Solution 2: directly pass `s`, seems like it will be implicitly converted to `string`

```
istringstream strin(s);
```

Solution 3: explicitly convert `s` to `string`

```
istringstream strin((string)(s));
```

Solution 4: add a pair of magical parentheses

```
istringstream strin((string(s)));
```

Solution 5: tell the compiler `s` is indeed a `char*` type

```
istringstream strin(string((char*)s));
```

All this works except the original one. Could anybody explain what is really going on here? Thanks.

Comment: search for: *Most vexing parse*.. read all about it.. ;), btw, my preference is for solution 2....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most vexing parse strikes again:

```
std::istringstream strin( string( s ) );
```

declares a function (`strin`) which takes a `string` as argument, and returns an `std::istringstream`.  (A good compiler could warn here, because there's no way you can possible implement such a function.)  The simplest way of correcting this is to add some extra parentheses:

```
std::stringstream strin( (string( s )) );
```

(Actually, the simplest solution here is to just write:

```
std::stringstream strin( s );
```

and let the implicit conversion do the job.)

Comment: Why is it impossible to implement this function? I thought streams are movable now.

Comment: or if the conversion has to be explicit, use C++11 uniform initialization: `std::stringstream strin{ string{ s } };`

Comment: *"A good compiler could warn here, because there's no way you can possible implement such a function"*. Why such function cannot be implemented? Is it because the stream classes are non-copyable? Or?

Comment: @jrok Ah, today yes.  But not unless you're using C++11 (and realistically, most people probably can't).

Comment: @Nawaz Yes.  But of course, C++ makes them movable, so the restriction no longer applies.  (Which in this case, it a good thing.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the "most vexing parse" issue.

```
istringstream strin(string(s));
```

This is not a `strin` variable declaration but a declaration of a function taking `string`, returning `istringstream` that is named `strin`.

You can fix this case like this. Notice the `+` there. While `s` is identifier, `+s` is an expression.

```
istringstream strin(string(+s));
```